# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'. > Please fix the version conflict Android

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services

I know there are many similar questions already, but all of their solutions mention adding

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

at the bottom of the gradle file, which I have. Or updating the google-services to 3.0.0 which I also have.

The error is:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies]
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'. 
Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.
Information:BUILD FAILED
```

Rolling back to com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0 works, but creates conflicts with Firebase which I'm completely unable to use. I'm trying to use play-services 9.4.0.

Here is my top level build graddle file:

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Here is my app-level gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.studio08.ronen.Zivug"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
//        debug {
//            debuggable true
//        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    // third-parties
    // https://github.com/lopspower/CircularImageView
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.2'
    // material design and appcompat
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha4'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
    // google
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.5.3'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0'
    //    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
    //    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'


}

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Remove

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
```

Because when you say: apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' you are including Google Play Services dependencies.
Tell me if works please.

Comment: Thank you this worked, I didn't see this anywhere in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Change the firebase core version

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0'
```

Remove

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
```

Comment: Thank you this worked. I didn't see as well that firebase wasn't updated.

Answer (score 1):

if anyone using       **classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'**

Just decrease the version to 3.0.0 (Don't know the reason). But working

```
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```